# Spring boot Oauth2 Facebook login - JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I was working with Spring boot `OAuth2` Facebook login, but I encountered the error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out
> of START_OBJECT token

The same code is working for Google and login works as expected. I am following this code on Github(https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo).

Can you please guide me to solve this issue?

## Below is the SecurityConfig details

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/public/**",
                    "/login",
                    "/register",
                    "/error",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/fonts/*.*",
                    "/webfonts/*.*",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")        
            .authorizationRequestRepository 
                        (cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
            .and()
            .redirectionEndpoint()
            .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
            .and()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Facebook successfully authenticates the login but when it callbacks my application this error appears.

Comment: this error mostly occurs when you try to parse 'JSON ' array which contain array or or object structure to your string could you please add more code and remove this unnecessary exception, your heading is sufficient

Comment: @v8-E, modified the Q, https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo is the code i used for my POC

Comment: Have you looked at this sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login#facebook-login

Comment: There is some guidance on an open ticket which closely resembles this issue.. worth checking out [Spring Security - GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6463)

Comment: For me, I added the correct IP address in my Facebook Login App and it got fixed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

[This issue has been fixed in 5.3.0 RELEASE.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6463) 
You can write custom access token requests and custom message converters. [Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-the-access-token-response) has a detailed guide on how to extend the existing functionality.

```
....
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .formLogin()
                .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                    "/error",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/oauth2/**","/login","/signup")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                    .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                    .and()
                    .tokenEndpoint()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient())
                    .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                    .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                    .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
    http.logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("https://../auth/logout");
    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}


private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient() {
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter =
            new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
    tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setTokenResponseConverter(new CustomAccessTokenResponseConverter());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);

    return tokenResponseClient;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the tutorial and I also had the same problem the error is in the properties you must delete this and it will work

https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/blob/master/spring-social/src/main/resources/application.yml

the error is this remove this properties or commit it

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.tokenUri= https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/oauth/access_token
```